# django-tinymce 1.5.2 no field to enter text

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

I create a blog and installed django-tinymce 1.5.2. But when configured as mentioned documentation, I have no field to enter text in the admin panel.

**My model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    DRAFT = "D"
    PUBLISHED = "P"
    POST_STATUS = (
        (DRAFT, "Draft"),
        (PUBLISHED, "Published"),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    text = HTMLField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=POST_STATUS, default=DRAFT, max_length=10)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ....
    'suit',
    'tinymce',
    ....
)

TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, 'tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = '/static/js/tiny_mce'
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace,print,textcolor",
    'theme': "modern",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
```

Comment: Have you added code to admins.py?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso No, what code?

Comment: try to add something like 
`class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    field = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 20}, )},
    }`

Comment: @RafaelCardoso In my console I have something like this - 304 code:
`[15/Apr/2015 16:11:58]"GET /tinymce/compressor/?js=true&diskcache=true&core=true&suffix=&themes=modern&plugins=table%2Cspellchecker%2Cpaste%2Csearchreplace%2Cprint%2Ctextcolor&languages=en HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[15/Apr/2015 16:11:59]"GET /static/suit/img/bg_left_white.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[15/Apr/2015 16:11:59]"GET /static/suit/img/glyphicons-halflings-white-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
`

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend testing that everything is installed correctly by following the instruction [here](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#testing). I just tried it and everything worked accept the settings file was named "testtinymce.settings" not "testtinymce.staticfiles_settings."

You can see examples of the Admin code such as below (/site-packages/testtinymce/testapp/admin.py).

As for the [304 code](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E304.html) - that just means the file has been cached locally and doesn't need to be retrieved again from the server.

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name in ('content1', 'content2'):
            return db_field.formfield(widget=TinyMCE(
                attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30},
                mce_attrs={'external_link_list_url': reverse('tinymce.views.flatpages_link_list')},
            ))
        return super(TinyMCETestInlineAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```